# Graphics card for dual 2560 x 1440 output

Tags: graphics-card, resolution, dvi, displayport

As the title suggests I want to power two 2560 x 1440 monitors from one graphics card.

I am just about to send my second graphics card back to Amazon, so before I purchase a 3rd incorrect card I thought I should get some advice.

My latest card has dual DL-DVI output but only supports 2560 x 1440 on one output, the other maxes out at 1920 x 1080.

**Can graphics cards with two Dual Link DVI adapters (or alternately, one Dual Link DVI and one DisplayPort support the a full 2560 x 1440 on both monitors, or does that depend on the graphics hardware and not only the connectors?**

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Product/purchasing recommendations are off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Would this fall outside the purchasing recommendations rule, seeing as they are asking more "does this product exist" than "what's the best one to buy"?

Comment: [Jeff Attwood uses a Radeon 7970](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/the-ips-lcd-revolution.html)

Comment: @techturtle - Not really, because this isn't hard to find.  OP even knows what he needs - a card with dual dual-link DVI.  (Of which there are lots.)

Comment: Well thanks a lot for just reading the last sentence of the question, when it should be pretty obvious that what I really wanted to know was do Dual DL-DVi cards support the required res, and my purchase was simply an aboration.

Comment: To answer your question, it's GPU-specific... some cards may support multiple dual link DVI but have a (total) framebuffer limit below the res you're trying to use.

Comment: @Shinrai, the OP doesn't know *that* he needs a card with dual dual-link DVI. He's asking **whether** such a card would support his res. It's a valid question and it does not necessarily have to involve references to specific products.

Comment: @Bender - By definition, dual-link DVI will do this.  So any limitations like that (ie, the card can only do one like that at a time but doesn't have the bandwidth for two) should be advertised, and if they aren't you were misled.  There are boatloads of cards at every price range that do this and have been for years (I know off the top of my head that the GeForce 7600GS did it and that was a $150 card when it came out *six years ago*.)

Answer (score 1):

You just need a video card that has two dual-link DVI ports.

The Geforce 600 series supports "[4 independent 2D displays, or 3 stereoscopic/3D displays (NV Surround)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_600_Series#Features)"

AMD cards with eyeinfinity that have two dual-link DVI ports should also support this.

[Here is an example of a card](http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=02G-P4-2670-KR) that has two dual-link dvi cables. This is not an endorsement of this product or a recommendation to buy. Just shop and look for a card that has two dual link DVI ports should be all you need.

It is possible to make a displayport connector into a dual-link dvi cable however that seems more expensive with adapters currently ranging in price from 60-$100

You could also opt for displays that support displayport 1.2 and a video card with that port as well.

"[For example, a DP 1.2-enabled notebook will be able to drive two WQXGA (2560×1600) monitors or four WUXGA (1920×1200) units over a single connector, with each display acting as an independent screen with different resolution and timings at full uncompressed pixel performance with HDCP copy protection.](http://www.geek.com/articles/chips/displayport-1-2-enables-full-4k-x-2k-resolution-3d-stereo-beyond-full-hd-and-more-20100118/)"